# Task Scheduling using AppConfig settings

Tags: c#, task, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have a config file with the following settings:

```
<add key ="Mode" value ="Daily"/>

<add key="ScheduledTime" value="16:30"/>
```

Based on these values in the config file, I need to schedule the job automatically in my C# program. I have tried this code but it throws an error:

> When converting string to datetime, parse the string to take the date
>   before putting each variable into DateTime object

```
TaskService ts = new TaskService()
TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "RMATask";

if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Mode") == "Daily")
{
    DailyTrigger daily = new DailyTrigger();
    daily.StartBoundary = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ScheduledTime"));
    daily.DaysInterval = 1;
    td.Triggers.Add(daily);
    td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"C:/Bigdata/bigdatadev/Framework/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe", null, null));
    ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Tablename"), td);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take that same value from .config and parse it as a `TimeSpan`.

```
var startTime = TimeSpan.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ScheduledTime"));
```

That will make `startTime` a `TimeSpan` equal to 16 hours and 30 minutes

(I'd put some validation around that and maybe not even read directly from `AppSettings` but that's another story.)

Then you can do

```
daily.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today + startTime;
```